# Filling regions created by plot[smooth] with color

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I would like to color each region of the picture by some color.
Tikz code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=none] at (3.5,3) {\scriptsize \ldots};
\node[draw=none] at (0.42,1.47) [text width=1cm] {\scriptsize $a.0 + 0$ $0 + a.0$ $a.0$ $a.0 \mid 0$ \ldots};
\node[draw=none] at (0.5,4.5) [text width=1.5cm] {\scriptsize $b.a.0$ $b.(a.0 + 0)$ \ldots};
\draw[preaction={draw, ultra thick, double distance=0pt}]
plot[smooth cycle]
coordinates{
  (0,0) (0,6) (6,6) (6,0)
};

\draw[preaction={draw, ultra thick, double distance=0pt}]
plot[smooth]
coordinates{
  (1.5,6.5) (1.5,4.5) (-0.6,2)
};

\draw[preaction={draw, ultra thick, double distance=0pt}]
plot[smooth]
coordinates{
  (1.5,4.5) (2,3) (1.5,-0.5)
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach by using draw order and clipping.

First, fill the regions with color going from the biggest to the smallest. Extend the regions a bit and and clip against the outer boundary,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% make outer plot as a command because it is used often during clipping
\newcommand{\outline}[0]{%
plot[smooth cycle]%
coordinates{%
  (0,0) (0,6) (6,6) (6,0)%
}}

%fill 
\fill[green] 
\outline;

\begin{scope}
    \clip \outline;
    \fill[blue] (1.5,-0.5) -- (-0.6,-0.5) -- (-0.6,2) -- (1.5,4.5) % extend the area to the corners
        plot[smooth] coordinates{ (1.5,4.5) (2,3) (1.5,-0.5) };
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
    \clip \outline;
    \fill[red] (1.5,6.5) -- (-1.5,6.5) -- (-0.6,2)  plot[smooth] coordinates{ (1.5,6.5) (1.5,4.5) (-0.6,2) };
\end{scope}
```

Second, draw the lines on top if it. I'm not sure what the postaction and double distance shall be fore, but if you just want to make the lines thicker than ultra use `line width` to set it to an arbitrary thickness:

```
% draw
\draw[line width=2.5pt]
\outline;

\draw[line width=2.5pt]
plot[smooth] coordinates{ (1.5,6.5) (1.5,4.5) (-0.6,2) };

\draw[line width=2.5pt, fill=blue]
plot[smooth] coordinates{ (1.5,4.5) (2,3) (1.5,-0.5) };

\node[draw=none] at (3.5,3) {\scriptsize \ldots};
\node[draw=none] at (0.42,1.47) [text width=1cm] {\scriptsize $a.0 + 0$ $0 + a.0$ $a.0$ $a.0 \mid 0$ \ldots};
\node[draw=none] at (0.5,4.5) [text width=1.5cm] {\scriptsize $b.a.0$ $b.(a.0 + 0)$ \ldots};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Never used clipping before so i was limited in my imagination :)